# Ray tracing using the Phong illumination model: bizarre color in lighting seemingly fixed by reducing light intensity?

Tags: c++, raytracing, lighting, phong

I'm writing a simple ray-tracer with lighting using Phong illumination model. But the problem is that there's part of the sphere display a whole different color. For example, the sphere should be only green in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwVyN.png).

[image: this]

I tried to reduce the light intensity, then it somehow displays correctly [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88fnV.png).

[image: like this]

This is the code for primary rays

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            Ray ray(gCamera);
            float x = iX + j * pSize;
            float y = iY - i * pSize;
            ray.v = vec3(x * scale, y * scale, 0) - gCamera;
            gPixels[i][j] = trace(ray);
        }
    }
```

And this is the code for the intersection (testing with sphere at origin without any transformation)

```
    double findIntersection(const Ray& ray) {
        dvec3 u = mXfmInverse * dvec4(ray.u, 1.0);
        dvec3 v = mXfmInverse * dvec4(ray.v, 0.0);

        double a = glm::dot(v, v);
        double b = 2 * glm::dot(u, v);
        double c = glm::dot(u, u) - 1;
        double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;

        if (delta < 0) return -1;
        double root = sqrt(delta);
        double t0 = 0.5 * (-b - root) / a;
        if (t0 >= 0) return t0;
        double t1 = 0.5 * (-b + root) / a;
        return t1 >= 0 ? t1 : -1;
    }
```

and calculating Phong illumination

```
    Material material = ray.sphere->getMaterial();

    // diffuse
    dvec3 center = ray.sphere->getXfm() * vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    dvec3 normal = glm::normalize(hitPoint - center);
    dvec3 lightDir = glm::normalize(light.position - hitPoint);
    double lambertian = max(glm::dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);

    // specular
    double specular = 0;
    if (lambertian > 0) {
        dvec3 viewDir = glm::normalize(-ray.v);
        dvec3 reflectDir = glm::reflect(-lightDir, normal);
        specular = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    }

    dvec3 color = lambertian * material.diffuse + specular * material.specular;
    return color * light.color;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the error is, but from looking at the RGB values of your example images it looks a lot like the "Green" component of your colour is wrapping past 255 back to 0, resulting in the purple colour you're seeing.

Comment: I have to agree. This seems like more a case where you have one of your values going out of range rather than an improper use of C++ anywhere. You will need to validate the range of each computations. [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) will help.

Comment: oh you're absolutely right, haven't thought of it. Preventing from exceeding 255 does work indeed, but I still don't know if it's the right way to do so. Anyway your comment does answer my question, if you could post it separately, I could mark it as an answer.

Comment: You could always `modulo` the results `256`, e.g. (`result % 256`) would always guarantee a value between `0 - 255`.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica will this would limit the range, wouldn't modulo result in other artifacts, as it would start the value a `0` again?  So something like `std::clamp` should be used instead?

Comment: You will have to try both. Not being fluent in the finer points of ray-tracing, I'm not positive. However if you just need to keep things in range and not wrap, limiting to a max of 255 would definitely be better that straying off out of range.